# Managing API requests with different levels of authentication

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, rest, oauth

I am building a RESTful API trying to understand how to access the API with different levels of authentication.

Those are my scenarios:

a) Web application "A" handles all the accounts and billing. It should be able to make calls to its own API.

b) Web application "B" (trusted by web application "A" and vice versa) should be able to make API calls to web application "A" to verify and create new accounts. "A" manages and stores all accounts.

c) Web application "B" has its own API and should also be able to make calls to its own API. "B" manages and stores all users (associated with an account in "A").

d) A 3rd party application "C" should be able to make API calls to application "B" on behalf of "B"'s users.

So... here are my questions:

1. How do you secure and authenticate API calls from an application to its own API? How would you call the own API? Just like an external application would?
2. Wouldn't it be bad performance to call an API method the same way as an external application would (say run a CURL GET https://api.example.com/accounts)? Or should internal APIs be called differently? (sorry if this question is stupid)
3. If "B" trusts "A" and vice versa: Do I need any authentication or authorization at all? Since there are no users involved, just accounts and business logic. Application "B" just needs to tell "A" for which account an operation should be done. But it is basically allowed to perform all these tasks for any account. Would it be okay to simply send "B"s client_key and client_secret along with the request parameters over HTTPS?
4. I guess I really only need oAuth for scenario d), right?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How do you secure and authenticate API calls from an application to
>      its own API? How would you call the own API? Just like an external
>      application would?

**I wouldn't use curl to access the API, using codeigniter you could create the API as a library and create a controller that calls the each libraries method. This would allow you to both generate an API that is web accessible via controller, and also load a library and access the methods directly.**

> 1. Wouldn't it be bad performance to call an API method the same way as
>      an external application would (say run a CURL GET
>      https://api.example.com/accounts)? Or should internal APIs be called
>      differently? (sorry if this question is stupid)

**Yes, like i mentioned in #1.**

> 1. If "B" trusts "A" and vice versa: Do I need any authentication or
>      authorization at all? Since there are no users involved, just
>      accounts and business logic. Application "B" just needs to tell "A"
>      for which account an operation should be done. But it is basically
>      allowed to perform all these tasks for any account. Would it be okay
>      to simply send "B"s client_key and client_secret along with the
>      request parameters over HTTPS?

**If you are accessing via http externally, i would recommend using an API key or some sort of token. If you are doing the controller/library route that i mentioned in #1. Then no.**

> 1. I guess I really only need oAuth for scenario d), right?

**Either oAuth or an API key system, that you provide the key to the user manually.**